# How to disable submit button if I add # as a pattern in a password field

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I enter `#` anywhere in my password field, my submit button should be disabled. Also, when I remove the `#` the submit button should be displayed as it was originally.

```js
function edValueKeyPress() {
  var edValue = document.getElementById("edValue");
  var s = edValue.value;
  var IbValue = document.getElementById("IbValue");
  if (s == "#") {
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false)
  } else if (s == "#") {
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="edValue" type="password" oninput="edValueKeyPress()"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="IbValue"></span>
```

Comment: Both your if and else conditions are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggle on value - here I am using a regex to test the content

```js
$(function() {
  $("#edValue").on("input", function() {
    var invalid = /[#?]/g.test(this.value);
    $('#IbValue').prop('disabled', invalid);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="edValue" type="password" /><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="IbValue" />
</form>
```

Plain JS:

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("edValue").addEventListener("input", function() {
    var invalid = /[#?]/g.test(this.value);
    document.getElementById("IbValue").disabled=invalid;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="edValue" type="password" /><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="IbValue" />
</form>
```

Comment: What if I want to exclude "?" as well

Comment: Thak you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use the return of `test` using a `regex` to disable the button or not:

```js
function edValueKeyPress() {
  const edValue = document.getElementById("edValue");
  $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', (/\#/g).test(edValue.value))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="edValue" type="password" oninput="edValueKeyPress()"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="IbValue"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery It will be simpler - just change edValueKeyPress body to

```
IbValue.disabled = edValue.value.match('#');
```

```js
function edValueKeyPress() {
  IbValue.disabled = edValue.value.match('#');
}
```

```html
<input id="edValue" type="password" oninput="edValueKeyPress()"><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="IbValue"></span>
```

Comment: It would still be recommended to use an unobtrusive event handler instead of inline code